# 'browser'と'chrome'の違いは何ですか？

Tags: javascript, firefox-webextension

[2 つめの WebExtension - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Walkthrough#choose_beast.js)の`choose_beast.js`のコード中で`chrome`となっている部分が、[英語版](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension#choose_beast.js)では`browser`となっています。どちらも同じように動作するようですが、これら2つの違いは何なのでしょうか？

Comment: 日本語版MDNでよくあることですが、単純に古い版の英語版のままになっていて、英語の最新版に追従できてないだけかと思います。英語版はある版から`browser`に変わっています。想像なので回答として投稿しませんが、FirefoxでChrome拡張機能を扱えるようになったタイミングで変数名を`chrome`から`browser`に変えたのではないでしょうか？ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension$compare?locale=en-US&to=1156264&from=1138609

Comment: これ以前(2016/03)に一度`chrome`から`browser`に変える変更が`breaks Chrome compat`(Chromeとの互換性の破れ?)が理由でrevertされてて興味深いですね。 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension$compare?locale=en-US&to=1027802&from=1026038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どちらもJavaScript APIの名前空間ですが、`chrome`はGoogle Chrome向けに作られた拡張機能の移植のために用意されています。より具体的には、`browser`では非同期処理のために`Promise`及びコールバックベースのAPIが利用できますが、`chrome`ではコールバックベースのAPIしか利用できないという違いがあります。

ちなみにGoogle Chromeでは`chrome`を、Edgeでは`browser`を使いますが、どちらもコールバックのみで`Promise`はサポートされていません。

参考：
Google Chrome: [JavaScript APIs - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)
Microsoft Edge: [Extensions - Supported APIs - Microsoft Edge Development | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis)
Mozilla Firefox: [JavaScript APIs - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API)